# How to change the contents of a class construcor in a javascript class and access it later?

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Edit: I have a [demo here](https://jsbin.com/jemafadosa/edit?html,js,console)

I want to fetch data from an API, add it to the constructor of a class, and then **on button Click** display it to the page.

```
class Entry {
  constructor() {
    this.pages = [];
  }
  loadAllEntries(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.pages = data;
        // this would do it autuomatically, it's not what I want
        //this.displayAllEntries("#notes-list");
      });
  }

  displayAllEntries(node) {
    let ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.id = "display-list-note";
    this.pages.map((page) => { 
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerText = page.title;
      ul.appendChild(this.createClickableItem(page));
    });
    document.querySelector(node).appendChild(ul);
  }
  createClickableItem(item) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = item.title;
    li.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(item.id);
    });
    return li;
  }
}

const courses = new Entry();
courses.loadAllEntries("http://localhost:1338/courses?favorite=true");

// on some click I want to run 

courses.displayAllEntries("#notes-list");
```

But, `displayAllEntries` acts as if `loadAllEntries` never ran!

later on I want to do something like `courses.deleteEntry(213)` and change the contents of the constructor, (a glorified todo list type of thing)

Edit: I have a [demo here](https://jsbin.com/jemafadosa/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: this is odd, have you checked if `this.pages` has been updated with the fetched data?

Comment: @kritiz only if within the the `fetch.then()`

Comment: @kritiz here's an example https://jsbin.com/jemafadosa/edit?html,js,console

Comment: ah i see, i think returning promise from `loadAllEntries` should work

Comment: `loadAllEntries` is using a Promise to handle loading and assigning the data. It's essentially an asynchronous function, without the `async` or `await` keywords. It's not waiting for the fetch call to finish before you call `displayAllEntrires()`.

Comment: i tried `setTimeout` of 4 seconds to log `courses.getList()` and could see `this.pages` have been updated with the fetched data. your code's working fine i guess

Comment: @Derek @kritiz is there a best way to do this where the timing is taken in consideration (I tried adding async/await and same thing. Or is `seTimeout` the way to go?

Comment: i would use async/await, depending where you're calling these functions. alternatively, you can use a notification system that tells your app when the data is done loading. setTimeout is only good for situations where you know exactly how much time you want to delay an activity by - it's not good for guessing how long API calls will take.

Comment: @Derek I tried `async loadAllEntries(url) { const res = await fetch(url); const data = await res.json(); this.pages = data}` and had no effect on `displayAllEntrires`

Comment: i used `settimeout` just to test the code if `this.pages` is getting the fetched data - and it worked as expected. check @danh's answer - that's what i meant by _returning a promise_ earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest touch that will fix this is as follows:

1. *return* the promise from the fetch

```
    loadAllEntries(url) {
      // just return, no further changes required
      return fetch(url)
        .then(...
```

2. At the top level, carry on *after* the fetch is done with `then`

```
const courses = new Entry();
const url = "http://localhost:1338/courses?favorite=true";
courses.loadAllEntries(url).then(() => {
  courses.displayAllEntries("#notes-list");
});
```

If the underlying methods work, this will work.